# why PlayStore showing very Previous old Version as soon as I upload new Build?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, google-play-services

My current version of android app is **6.4.0** . but it shows **4.8.0** to general users as **downloadable** every time as soon as I upload new version to PlayStore before it gets accepted . I am getting this issue everytime, I googled about the issue but could not find any solution or reason for this problem. Have any one faced same problem, I am seeking sloution to this problem .Thank you

Comment: are you using staged rollouts? it allows to rollout app to only some % of the total users. if you want to roll out to all users, make it to 100% while creating a new release. also check [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en) to increase staged percentages

Comment: I am already doing it @Niraj

Answer (score 0):

If you increased the `minSdkVersion` or permissions after the 4.8.0 version, it keeps the old version available for those older devices that are no longer supported by newer versions of your app.

Comment: That is different case @Tenfour04 but in my case  if new Device without app search for app in playstore  (while app is in review), in the situation ,only 4.8.0 is shown  to new users also instead  it must have to be shown ...6.3.0 instead

Comment: If your revision is still under review, it should be invisible and does not exist to customers browsing the store. Doesn’t that make sense?

Comment: My concern is If 6.4.0 is my current version in playstore ,and if I upload 7.4.0 in playstore (in review)...then 4.8.0 must not be the available playstore ....instead i belive 6.4.0 is to be downloadable by new users who search my app in Playstore . which is not happening in my scenario